# Visiting Canada and back on WT/WB admission

Tags: usa, multiple-entry

Is it possible to go for a quick visit to Canada while the US before going back to one's home country flying from the US ?
Would one be denied re-entry even if the stamp on the passport is still valid ?
Cheers,
E